# how to create a custom s-function in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

What is the block that I can use for the creating a custom s-function in simulink?

I want to use C code using S-Function.. I know that there are functions that I have to define but I don't know how to reach it or which code to start with exactly..

Note: I am totally new to matlab and simulink..

Comment: There are lots of demo's that you can look at.  Type "sfundemos" (without the quotes) at the MATLAB command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `S-function Builder` block from Simulink's library (in Simulink->User Defined Functions). You can set number of states, inputs, outputs and also add code for calculating the derivatives + outputs. When you press `Build` it generates `C` code and you can start with that as a template. Or you could use the `S-function Builder` interface for writing all your code.

**Edit**: Matlab also has a built-in template that you can access:

```
edit([matlabroot,'/simulink/src/sfuntmpl_basic.c']);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful because I didn't knew that the S-function Builder can generate for me the template code..

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the MATLAB documentation on this?
It is usually pretty complete, once you find the right page to read.

For s-functions there e.g. is

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/sfg/how-to-implement-s-functions.html

which includes links to example s-functions you can find in your matlab-installation.

Comment: I already read this document and I wass just locking for the block that can generate for me the c code so I can write my code